# Multiple SSH from same host - too many auth failures

Tags: ssh, terminal

I have multiple websites hosted with the same provider. This means that access via SSH is the same 'host' for all.

I have been adding a version of the following to my SSH config file for each site:

```
Host shell.grid.co.uk
User testuser
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_testuser
```

I now have 6 sites in my config and am unable to connect to SSH via terminal.

I am getting the following error:

> Received disconnect from [IP ADDRESS] port 22:2: Too many
>   authentication failures for [USER]

I have been doing some research and wonder if this has something to do with `MaxAuthTries`?

If I remove 1 or more of the items from the config file, I can then log on via SSH on terminal.

All of these websites are on a shared hosting platform, if that makes any difference.

Comment: are you using `ControlMaster` to bundle duplicate connections over the first one?

Comment: @thrig No. I'm pretty new to SSH. I'm learning, but its a rather steep learning curve. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track, but I think you might benefit from breaking out the configuration with aliases for each user within your `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host site1
  HostName shell.grid.co.uk
  User site1user
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_site1user

Host site2
  HostName shell.grid.co.uk
  User site2user
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_site2user

Host sitetest
  HostName shell.grid.co.uk
  User testuser
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_testuser
```

This way your SSH client should only use the one specific key for each user.  You would simply `ssh site1` and your configuration would add the correct username and private key.

Comment: Thank you! That has worked. I will read up on the use of 'host'.